# Change the value of Info.plist key programmatically in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, info.plist

Can we change the value of **info.plist** key programmatically in **ios**? 
 like I want to change the value of **'View controller-based status bar appearance'** key to **'YES' / 'NO'** in different places.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change values in the info.plist programmatically.

What you can do:

1. Set "ViewControllerBased status bar appearance" to Yes
2. Make a superclass for all your viewcontrollers (For example: "BaseViewController")
3. Override method

   (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
4. Set your default style there
5. Override this method in any other subclass where want you to differ from that style

Comment: thanks.. but I know about this solution.. doing that will lead me to make changes in all the files.. which i don't want to do that's why looking for another options..

Comment: solved? please tell solution. thank you